# From where can I get 3D models of USS Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

I want to include USS Enterprise in my personal non-commercial 3D projects. I can always create a 3D model of USS Enterprise by myself. But, I think, there's no point of re-inventing the wheel again.

Are original official models of USS Enterprise public? Or, can I get them from somewhere?
Is there any exact 3D blueprint (with dimension details) to speedup building process?

Comment: Which model, specifically? NCC-1701 (TOS)? A? B? C? D? E? Rebooted Enterprise? ST:ENT?

Comment: @bitmask All models of Enterprise.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple Google search.  Enter "Enterprise 1701" (and A,B,C,D, or E) and the file extension of the 3d software you use (e.g. ".ps3" for poser).  On the first page you should find several dozen links to each model.

Comment: None are legitimate...

Comment: @SachinShekhar - what exactly do you mean by "legitimate"?  For non-commercial use most of them are share-ware (i.e. you can use them as long as you credit the creator), and frequently they are better than the official meshes.  You won't find any official meshes online